# Error python selenium: Message: session not created: cannot process extension #1 from unknown error: cannot read manifest

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am currently facing an issue with a web scraping task I am undertaking. The webpage I am attempting to scrape employs reCAPTCHA v3, which poses a significant challenge to my scraping efforts. ReCAPTCHA v3, a widely used tool to prevent automated access to websites, operates in the background without requiring any user interaction, making it particularly challenging to bypass or overcome.

This is the project structure.

[image]

```py
def start_driver():
    try:
        
        url = 'https://antcpt.com/anticaptcha-plugin.zip'
        filehandle, _ = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url)
        with zipfile.ZipFile(filehandle, "r") as f:
            f.extractall("plugin")
        api_key = "MY API KEY"
        file = Path('./plugin/js/config_ac_api_key.js')
        file.write_text(file.read_text().replace("antiCapthaPredefinedApiKey = ''", "antiCapthaPredefinedApiKey = '{}'".format(api_key)))

        zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile('./plugin.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk("./plugin"):
                for file in files:
                    path = os.path.join(root, file)
                    zip_file.write(path, arcname=path.replace("./plugin/", ""))
        zip_file.close()

        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_extension('./plugin.zip')
        chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
        return driver
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error al iniciar el controlador:", e)
        return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = start_driver()
```

but I get an error

```
Message: session not created: cannot process extension #1 from unknown error: cannot read manifest
```